# Difference between queryAtLocation and queryWithRegion?

Tags: objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I understand queryAtLocation queries locations within a certain radius but what is queryWithRegion? How does it differ from queryAtLocation?

https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A location with a radius is represented as a circle, but a region with a span becomes a rectangle.